# Datagrid show empty lines even that the datagrid keeps the values

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Using WPF,
Im having issues where the datagrid's data isn't being rendered and i can only see empty lines. (some data IS being inserted, debugged.)
Even that the datagrid keeps the values in dg.ItemsSource its still show empty lines.

XML code:

```
        <DataGrid Name="dg"  Initialized="dg_Initialized" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Extended">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Type}" Header="Type"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding InventoryID}" Header="InventoryID"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Location}" Header="Location"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding InStock}" Header="InStock"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding StockCount}" Header="StockCount"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}" Header="Price"/>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Back-end Code:

Im adding every product to the collection
and finally im adding the collection to datagrid items source.

```
        data = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        productsList = bl.FindProductByName(""); // Get List of products
        for (int i = 0; i < productsList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (productsList[i] != null)
                  data.Add(productsList[i]);
        }

        dg.ItemsSource = data;
```

Product Holds:

```
Name - string
Type - string
InventoryID - Integer
Location - Integer
InStock - Bool
StockCount - Integer
Price - Integer
```

Comment: As I see, you've turned column autogeneration off. Have you created columns by hand? If so, how are they configured?

Comment: Your question does not contains enough information, provide more details  like in what method the data is set or as Aloraman said how the columns get created?

Comment: yes i created columns by hand i edit now @Aloraman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important that all the members you show are public, if not they won't be visible in the grid. Try creating a public get method to your properties if you don't have one.

EDIT:

```
<DataGrid  Name="DataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="*"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

Public class Person {
 private String pm_Name = "";
}

Public String Name { 
  get { return pm_Name; } 
  set { pm_Name = value;} 
}

List<Person> Persons = new List<Persons>();
Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = Sam });
Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = Peter });

DataGrid1.ItemsSource = Persons;
```

This example should work. So basically to describe it I use a List with objects as I set to my grids itemssource.

After that I go to my xaml and I bind the path of my objects property in this case 'Name'.

If you wanna use a list/collection that can keep an eye on changes in your lists objects, you use ObservableCollections like you already use.

Hope this example helps you in your quest of success.

Comment: still doesnt work. same results. The grid knows about all of 4 products that i saved. Even if i sorted by type product , his do it but still only show empty cells @Max Mazur

Comment: I'll create a simple datagrid example for you to see if you have all the right things in order. stay tuned :)

Comment: A thing i noticed. You set your ItemsSource in code behind AND in xaml, maybe that could be the reason for trouble. Try to remove the xaml part since you already do it in code behind.

If i recall correctly an ItemsSource of a control cannot be set twice.

Comment: i haved changed all of mine get set method to your way: Public String Name { 
  get { return pm_Name; } 
  set { pm_Name = value;}  and its works !!! thanksssss